# Hapi/Joi validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, hapi.js

What does these with() and without() function do in Joi validation?

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    password: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$/),
    access_token: [Joi.string(), Joi.number()],
    birthyear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013),
    email: Joi.string().email()
}).with('username', 'birthyear').without('password', 'access_token');
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#objectwithkey-peers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [hapijs API Reference](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#objectwithkey-peers):

> **`object.with(key, peers)`**
>
> Requires the presence of other keys whenever
>   the specified key is present where:
>
> `key` - the reference key.
>
> `peers` - the required peer key names that must
>   appear together with key. `peers` can be a single string value or an
>   array of string values.

Translated to your example that means "When the key `username` is present the key `birthyear` must also be present".

> **`object.without(key, peers)`**
>
> Forbids the presence of other keys whenever
>   the specified is present where:
>
> `key` - the reference key.
>
> `peers` - the forbidden peer key names that
>   must not appear together with key. `peers` can be a single string value
>   or an array of string values.

Translated to your example that means "When the key `password` is present then the key `access_token` is not allowed to be present too".

Answer (score 0):

`.with(keyA, keyB)` means that keyB must be present when keyA is present.

*Your schema example makes no good use of `.with()` since "username" is a required key. You could then make "birthyear" required too.*

`.without(keyA, keyB)` means that keyB must **NOT** be present when keyA is present.